# Using boost::spirit::qi::symbols

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use `boost::spirit::qi::symbols` to parse enumeration values. My code is like the following:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

enum class Foo { None, Bar = 42, Baz = 43 };

struct FooValues: qi::symbols<char, Foo>
{
    FooValues() { add("Bar", Foo::Bar)("Baz", Foo::Baz); }
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::iterator Iterator;
    typedef qi::space_type Skipper;
    using qi::rule;

    rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> foo = qi::lit("Foo") >> '.' >> FooValues();
    rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> root = foo | ('\"' >> foo >> '\"');

    std::string input = "Foo.Bar";
    Foo output;
    if (qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), root, Skipper(), output))
        cout << "output: " << static_cast<int>(output) << endl;
    else
        cout << "failed" << endl;
}
```

However it fails parsing the input. If I replace the rule for parsing enumeration value by the following it works.

```
rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> foo = qi::lit("Foo") >> '.' >>
  ((qi::lit("Bar") >> qi::attr(Foo::Bar)) | (qi::lit("Baz") >> qi::attr(Foo::Baz)));
```

What am I doing wrong? I would prefer using the `qi::symbols` parser as it would allow me to add values in a loop instead of manually writing them into the rule.

Replacing the `FooValues()` temporary by a local variable like the following works, but I would prefer not to create extra variables if not needed. Is that possible?

```
FooValues fooValues;
rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> foo = qi::lit("Foo") >> '.' >> fooValues;
```

Answer (score 3):

Spirit rule hold its components by reference, so you have to ensure that the referenced components stay in scope and does not get destructed while it is being referenced. Look at the code

```
rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> foo = qi::lit("Foo") >> '.' >> FooValues();
```

Instance of FooValues gets out of scopes before the rule is used. You can fix it in such way

```
FooValues values;
rule<Iterator, Foo(), Skipper> foo = qi::lit("Foo") >> '.' >> values;
```

Comment: I see that the temporary is an issue. However I wonder how does `qi::lit` work? It looks like a temporary as well.